# Get the list of the products which doesn’t have any orders across all the months and year as

Tags: c#, sql

I want the list of the products which doesn’t have any orders across all the months and year.

Here is my query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(p.ProductName), 
DATEPART(MM,o.OrderDate),DATEPART(YY,o.OrderDate) 
FROM Products p 
JOIN [Order Details] od on p.ProductID = od.ProductID
JOIN Orders o on o.OrderID = od.OrderID
GROUP BY (p.ProductName), DATEPART(MM,o.OrderDate),DATEPART(YY,o.OrderDate)
```

Comment: Please give more information about what you expect, you can share example of table data and expected output. It is not clear for understanding

Comment: Do you have a calendar/dates table in your db?

Comment: you want to make sure that a product has no sale in a specific year?

Comment: Note that DISTINCT is not a function

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide 30 rows of sample data for each table, and expected results of the query based on that sample data.

Answer (score 2):

Use `not exists`:

```
select p.*
from products p
where not exists (select 1
                  from Orders o join
                       [Order Details] od
                       on o.OrderID = od.OrderID
                  where p.ProductID = od.ProductID and
                        year(o.orderdate) = ?
                 );
```

`?` is for the year of interest.

Answer (score 0):

I used classes in code below to simulate your database.  See if this code works

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<Product> Products = new List<Product>();
            List<Order> Orders = new List<Order>();

            var results = (from o in Orders
                          join p in Products on o.ProductID equals p.ProductID
                          select new {order = o, name = p.ProductName})
                          .OrderByDescending(x => x.order.OrderDate)
                          .GroupBy(x => x.order.ProductID)
                          .Select(x => x.FirstOrDefault()) //get last order for each product
                          .Where(x => x.order.OrderDate < DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-6))
                          .Select(x => new { Name = x.name, ID = x.order.ProductID, Date = x.order.OrderDate})
                          .ToList();
        }
    }
    public class Product
    {
        public string ProductName { get; set; }
        public string ProductID { get; set; }
    }
    public class Order
    {
        public DateTime OrderDate { get; set; }
        public string ProductID { get; set; }
    }
}
```

---

Ths code is more efficient since it doesn't have to join itmes that are not needed

```
            var results = Orders.OrderByDescending(x => x.OrderDate)
                          .GroupBy(x => x.ProductID)
                          .Select(x => x.FirstOrDefault()) //get last order for each product
                          .Where(x => x.OrderDate < DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-6))
                          .Select(x => new { Name = Products.Where(y => y.ProductID == x.ProductID).FirstOrDefault().ProductName , ID = x.ProductID, Date = x.OrderDate })
                          .ToList();
```

---

If there are no orders for a product use following

```
            var resultsx = (from o in Orders
                           join p in Products on o.ProductID equals p.ProductID into ps 
                           from p in ps.DefaultIfEmpty() 
                           select new { order = o, name = p.ProductName })
                           .OrderByDescending(x => x.order == null ? new DateTime() : x.order.OrderDate)
                          .GroupBy(x => x.order.ProductID)
                          .Select(x => x.FirstOrDefault()) //get last order for each product
                          .Where(x => x.order == null ? true : x.order.OrderDate < DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-6))
                          .Select(x => new { Name = x.name, ID = x.order == null ? "" : x.order.ProductID, Date = x.order == null ? new DateTime() : x.order.OrderDate })
                          .ToList();
```